# How to update the extended UserRole of Identity User Role in .NET Core 2

Tags: .net-core

We have an extended of **Identity User (ApplicationUser)**, **Role (ApplicationRole)** and **UserRole (ApplicationUserRole)**.

We managed to save changes for ApplicationUser BUT **NOT** be able to save changes on ApplicationUserRole using the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Guid id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var userToUpdate = await _context.Users
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id.ToString());

        var userRoleToUpdate = await _context.UserRoles
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserId == id.ToString());

        // null means User was deleted by another user.
        if (userToUpdate == null || userRoleToUpdate == null)
        {
            return await HandleDeletedUser();
        }

        // Update the RowVersion to the value when this entity was
        // fetched. If the entity has been updated after it was
        // fetched, RowVersion won't match the DB RowVersion and
        // a DbUpdateConcurrencyException is thrown.
        // A second postback will make them match, unless a new 
        // concurrency issue happens.

        _context.Entry(userToUpdate)
            .Property("RowVersion").OriginalValue = User.RowVersion;

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUser>(
            userToUpdate,
            "User",
            s => s.FirstName, s => s.LastName, s => s.Email))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUserRole>(
                   userRoleToUpdate,
                   "UserRole",
                   s => s.RoleId.ToString()))
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }


                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var exceptionEntry = ex.Entries.Single();
                var clientValues = (ApplicationUser)exceptionEntry.Entity;
                var databaseEntry = exceptionEntry.GetDatabaseValues();
                if (databaseEntry == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save. " +
                        "The user was deleted by another user.");
                    return Page();
                }

                var dbValues = (ApplicationUser)databaseEntry.ToObject();
                await setDbErrorMessage(dbValues, clientValues, _context);

                // Save the current RowVersion so next postback
                // matches unless an new concurrency issue happens.

                User.RowVersion = (byte[])dbValues.RowVersion;

                // Must clear the model error for the next postback.
                ModelState.Remove("User.RowVersion");
            }
        }

        return Page();


    }
```

Any pointer for this? I assumed that we need to break up the save changes. Do the User first and then UserRole, doesn't it?

Also, we didn't implement the **RowVersion** for **ApplicationUserRole** which I believe is too overkill.

**Environment:**
.Net Core 2.1

**UPDATE - 1:**

Exception - 
InvalidOperationException: The passed expression of expression node type 'Call' is invalid. Only simple member access expressions for model properties are supported.

**UPDATE- 2:**

I've changed to this and no error BUT no changes on Roles:

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUserRole>(
                   userRoleToUpdate,
                   "UserRole",
                   ur => ur.UserId, ur => ur.RoleId))
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
```

How do we map work in relation to updating this RoleId from the dropdown list as on the edit form (Edit.html) ?!?!

```
<div class="form-group">
            Role:
            <select asp-for="User.UserRoles.ElementAt(0).RoleId" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="@Model.RoleNameSL">
                <option value="">-- Select Role --</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="User.UserRoles.ElementAt(0).Role" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE - 3:**

This is quite interesting. I changed the text from "UserRole" to "":

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUserRole>(
                   userRoleToUpdate,
                   "",
                   ur => ur.RoleId))
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
```

and now we have an error saying which I think this is getting close:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'RoleId' on entity type
>   'ApplicationUserRole' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or
>   marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with
>   an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke
>   'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.

Is it possible because we have this in our ApplicationDBContext ? In that case, what is the best way to update this then?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{

       ....  

        // Many to Many relationship - ApplicationUserRole

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting exception? why you could not savechanges for ApplicationUserRole? can you be more specific?

Comment: @Simonare - I've updated the exception above

Comment: and in which line are you getting this exception? I am trying to narrow down the problem

Comment: @Simonare - at this line                    `if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUserRole>( ...` ... looks like not even reaching the SaveChanges part ?!?!

Comment: @Simonare - I've updated and see "Updated - 2" ... any ideas?

Comment: @Simonare - I've continued troubleshoot this and updated this - "Update - 3"

Comment: Are you trying to update a Role itself, or just trying to update the Role that a user is assigned? If the latter why not use the UserManager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1.

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer - I'm not trying to update the Role. I'm trying to update UserRole ie. that user is assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using AspNetIdentity, which it looks like you are, you should be able to update the role using `UserManager`. UserManager is a part of Identity and is intended for managing the Identity of a user. As long as your roles are `AspNetRoles` then injecting `UserManager` will let you update any user to any predefined role.

Adding

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public Controller(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManger, ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{ 
    _userManager = userManger;
}

public async Task UpDateRole(string userId)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, "RoleName");
}
```

should do what you want, you might also want to remove that user from the role they were previously in.

Comment: Thanks for this. We aware about this. But due to we have extended the SaveChanges as we accomodate other fields ie. isDeleted, DeletedBy, DeletedDate etc etc plus at the same time utilising RowVersion as well. We are trying to stick with this approach. But I think we are getting close with this NOT updating BUT just removing it and then add back in for the new UserRole. The thing is we still worked out how to compare the old Role with the new one in this case from this form.

Comment: Continuing on this. I've posted on different post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936571/how-to-compare-the-value-between-the-one-from-database-and-the-change-net-core