# How to compare the value between the one from database and the client .Net Core 2

Tags: mvvm, .net-core

We have this edit Razor pages (edit.cshtml) which is extended from the following page model and it's very basic only include the PopulateRolesDropDownList:

```
public class RoleNamePageModel : PageModel
{
    public SelectList RoleNameSL { get; set; }

    public void PopulateRolesDropDownList(ApplicationDbContext _context,
        object selectedRole = null)
    {
        var rolesQuery = from d in _context.Roles
                               orderby d.Name // Sort by name.
                               select d;

        RoleNameSL = new SelectList(rolesQuery,
                    "RoleId", "Name", selectedRole);
    }

}
```

Also in this Edit page, we added:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="User.UserRoles.ElementAt(0).RoleId" name="User.Current.RoleId" />
```

We also do the [BindProperty] in the code behind

```
public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

We need to find out whether there is a change on this model. What is the approach to do this?

**ENVIRONMENT:**

- .NET Core 2.2
- Razor Pages

**UPDATE - 1:**

On the PostAsync, we made another call to the database:

```
var userRoleToUpdate = await _context.UserRoles
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserId == id.ToString());
```

We just need to compare this value with the change on a drop-down list or not. We could not work how.

**UPDATE - 2:**

We did change as per recommend by @NevilleNazerane below:

```
public class AssignClubUserViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public Guid SelectedRoleID { get; set; }

    }

    [BindProperty]
    public AssignClubUserViewModel AssignClubUser { get; set; }
```

and added OnGetAsync:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return NotFound();

        var user = await _context.Users
                        .Include(u => u.ClubApplicationUsers)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id.ToString());

        AssignClubUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        AssignClubUser.LastName = user.LastName;
        AssignClubUser.UserName = user.UserName;
        AssignClubUser.SelectedClubID = 
        user.ClubApplicationUsers.ElementAt(0).ClubID;

        ....
```

Is this right? I got the error: NullReferenceException: Arg_NullReferenceException on line  AssignClubUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;

**UPDATE - 3:**

Fixed by creating a ModemView and then on the OnGetAsync() for query ensure to mapped with the ModelView:

```
var user = await _context.Users
                            .Include(u => u.ClubApplicationUsers)
                            .Where(t => t.Id == id.ToString())
                            .Select(t => new AssignClubUserViewModel<ApplicationUser>
                            {
                                FirstName = t.FirstName,
                                LastName = t.LastName,
                                UserName = t.UserName,
                                SelectedClubID = t.ClubApplicationUsers.ElementAt(0).ClubID
                            }).SingleAsync();
```

Comment: what "change" are you referring to?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane - sorry I just change the title. It refers to a client.

Comment: by client you mean when the end user changes dropdown (select)?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane ... correct

Comment: in that case can you add your select html code? because this is supposed to happen by default

Comment: @NevilleNazerane can you show us on how to get this value then? Both from the hidden field as well as dropdownlist in this case?

Comment: I am looking into the exact syntax for `SelectList` but I just noticed you used "RoleId" instead of "Id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a view model, I recommend you simplify your bindings and let your behind code handle the other functionalities. You can first make a `SelectedRoleId` property:

```
public int SelectedRoleId { get; set; }
```

In your view model, you can assign this property's default value to `User.UserRoles.ElementAt(0).RoleId` in either your constructor or your `OnGet`, based on how you need it set up. This way the drop down is bound to a simple property.

For binding dropdowns (HTML selects) .NET Core provides the `asp-items` tag helper.

```
<select asp-for="SelectedRoleId" asp-items="Model.RoleNameSL"></select>
```

In your `OnPostAsync`, you can use `SelectedRoleId` to access the selected value.

Comment: @nevillenazarane - in our case we binding into `<select asp-for="User.UserRoles.ElementAt(0).RoleId" ` ...

Comment: Also ... we managed to get  a list and populated the dropdownlist, and we even preselected a well. But we just want get the value of changed dropdownlist on the `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Guid id)` ... so we can do the some other stuff that we need

Comment: is `User` property in your view model? I would recommend making a separate property `SelectedRoleId` in your view model and setting and getting it in the behind code. I don't see the point of binding to something that complex when you already have a view model

Comment: Fixed by creating a ModemView and then on the OnGetAsync()  ... see UPDATE - 3